# Table for checklist MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set up a few checklists, which users can save & go back to. I haven't set up user profiles yet.

How should I set up MySQL database? So far I have one database (e.g. lists_db), and am creating a new table for each separate list. Is this the right way to do it?

Also, what fields shall I have? ID presumably, and then what? How does MySQL read checkboxes?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: "How does MySQL read checkboxes?" I have some bad news for you...

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the questions and answers or just the answers?   If you just had one list, you could create a table for the questions (columns `question_id, question_text`) and a table for the answers (columns `question_id, user_id, checked`).

You could create a new table for every list, but this might be cumbersome. With two separate tables, it's possible to add a column to the questions (`question_group_id`) and store everything in a single column.

Regarding how MySQL reads checkboxes, databases generally don't store information specific to a UI component. In this case, the underlying data element is a boolean indicating whether it is checked or not - or in MySQL, a bit datatype.

Comment: Can you explain that last bit pls? How do I write that in MySQL? E.g. so far I have: CREATE TABLE lists (ID INT, List CHAR(25), Name CHAR(25)....what do I put in for the checkbox column?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may be conflating persistence with user interface.  MySQL has no notion of a 'check box'.  Rather, a database is a representer of facts:  It will remember the information you ask it to remember, but it makes no attempt at organizing that information in a way that's useful to a particular application.

As for remembering whether a box has been checked, you most likely want `BOOLEAN` (a synonym for `TINYINT(1)`.  You would represent an unchecked box with a value of zero, and a checked box with a non-zero value.